# How to get correct origin when using fetch() in Firefox developer console?

Tags: javascript, cors, firefox-developer-tools

Internal page at my work produces some big JSON file on a normal GET request that has some info in it. I wanted to fetch it directly in browser and filter and print what I need. So the starting code would look like this:

```js
(async ()=>{
  const req = await fetch(location.href);
  const data = await req.json();
  console.log(data);
})()
```

But this fails with the error:

```
Content-Security-Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://internalsite.com/jsoninfo.json
```

The site does have `strict-origin-when-cross-origin` referrer policy. But it sounds to me like GET request to the exact same URL I am on should always pass.

The problem is, if I look at the request I just made, I see this:

```
GET /jsoninfo.json undefined
Host: internalsite.com
User-Agent: --REDACTED--
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: null
```

So the origin is `null`, also instead of HTTP version there is `undefined` for some reason. And there is no referer header.

How can I get Firefox dev tools to send the correct origin when making XHR requests from dev console?

Comment: This is what happens when you issue requests from the Console tab on a new Firefox tab (i.e. with `about:newtab` in the address bar). Try sending the same request from `https://example.com` and things will be different.

Comment: It could be because Firefox treats JSON tabs as its internal tabs. Firefox developper edition will automatically convert JSON responses to interactive HTML document. I'll see if I have to same result if I turn that feature off.

Comment: Do you use the same protocol, host and port when you send the request as those you are using with the loaded page?

Comment: I am voting to close this question of mine, but if you arrived here from search engine:

The problem was that Firefox Dev edition beautifies the JSON responses, but considers this new beautified view to be exclusive browser tab, like `about:blank`. So it no longer sends the correct origin and CORS does not work.